# Create conditional variable in multiple data.tables (or data.frames)

Tags: r, loops, dplyr

I want to execute the same action in multiple data.tables (or data.frames). For example, I want to create the same variable conditional on the same rule in all data.tables.

A simple example can be (df1=df2=df3, without loss of generality here)

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1), var2 =c(20, 10, 10, 10, 20), var3 = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1), var2 =c(20, 10, 10, 10, 20), var3 = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9))
df3 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1), var2 =c(20, 10, 10, 10, 20), var3 = c(10, 8, 15, 7, 9))
```

My approach was: (i) to create a list of the data frames (list.df), (ii) to loop on this list trying to create the variable:

list.df

```
list.df<-vector('list',3)
for(j in 1:3){
  name <- paste('df',j,sep='')
  list.df[j] <- name
}
```

My (bad) tentative:

```
for(i in 1:3){
  a<-get(paste(list.df[[i]], "$var1", sep=""))
  b<-get(paste(list.df[[i]], "$var2", sep=""))
  name<-paste(list.df[[i]], "$var.new", sep="")
  assign(name, ifelse(a==2 & b==10, 1, 0))
}
```

Clearly `r` cannot create this new variable the way I am doing as I get a error message "object not found".
Any clues on how to fix my bad code? I have a feeling that `dplyr` could help me but I don't know how.

Comment: I get some error with the tentative code block.  Can you show the expected output

Comment: Yes, exactly. There is an error of "object not found" because my tentative is not working, @akrun. I should write "bad tentative". Apologies for that.

Comment: Just noticed that.  Using `$` will not work as intended.  Also, are you creating new variable 'var.new' in each dataset?

Comment: I thought the $ would not work, but I honestly don't know how to approach the problem in another way. I didn't create 'var.new' beforehand. In fact, I thought on doing that but I realized that I ended up using the same approach (the bad tentative) and so it didn't work.

Comment: Please try the solution posted below.  From the code showed, I guess  you need to create a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mget` after creating the strings of object names with `paste` so that we get the values ie. data.frames in a `list`.  We loop through the `list` (`lapply(...,`) and `transform` each dataset by creating the variable ('varNew') which is a binary variable.  We can either use `ifelse` on the logical statement or just wrap with `+` to coerce the TRUE/FALSE to 1/0.

```
lst <- lapply(mget(paste0('df', 1:3)), transform, 
           varNew = +(var1==2 & var2==10))
```

If we need to update the original objects, we can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(lst, envir = .GlobalEnv)
df1
df2
```

Comment: I just realized that `varNew` was not stored in the data.frames (r shows the right result but doesn't store the variable). Any idea how I can fix this?